# Advantage of incremental delivery

Tags: salesforcedx, git, release, jenkins, deliverability

We are using a full strategy to deliver our package in production (we make a package with all metadata) and we hesitate to switch to an incremental strategy (send package only with metadata we create/ modify since last release + destructive).

According to you, what are the advantages of incremental strategy ? Is it worth to switch from full to incremental?

For more precision, we are using sfdx and a git repo as source. Packages are builded and delivered with Jenkins using our git repo

Answer (score 3):

Incremental packages reduce bandwidth usage and the amount of time needed to validate the package. Also, if your update only covers non-unit-test features, you can skip running unit tests, which may easily take an hour or more in large orgs. Overall, this means faster deployment times over deploying all components.

Also, consider the fact that deployments are limited to a maximum file size and component count (10,000 for non-AppExchange packages), which means eventually, you might not have a choice but to move to incremental packages. There's no real advantage to deploying your entire org every time you change a single file.

Comment: just need to know how can we create a **package version** containing only the last updates?

Comment: @dibocor If you're using Package Versions (Unlocked Packages), each version is always a full snapshot of the data, but on install, only delta changes are applied to the org. This allows you to upgrade/downgrade to any version at any time, assuming all dependencies are satisfied. That said, your best performance will come about if you use multiple packages to make them as small as possible, as this minimizes deployment times.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for your reply. I see now